# Мгновенное добавление данных C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity

Для кнопки добавления данных в таблицу сделал такой код:

```
context.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("Изменения внесены.");
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы данные мгновенно вносились в таблицу? Новая строка появляется только при переходе на прошлую форму и обратно.

Comment: Указывайте тип приложения в метках. А так, вам поможет `ObservableCollection`, поизучайте вопрос.

Comment: скорее всего @aepot прав и вы делаете где-то в коде `dataSource = context.Set<X>().Local.ToList()`, а нужно `dataSource = context.Set<X>().Local.ToBindingList()`

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение wpf, то вам лучше создать коллекцию `ObservableCollection`
И привязать её к `ItemsSource`

```
ListBoxSetting.ItemsSource = Setting_;

ObservableCollection<Setting> Setting_ = new ObservableCollection<Setting>();
Setting_.CollectionChanged += ListBoxSetting_CollectionChanged; // Добавляем событие изменения коллекции

 foreach (var setting in result)
 Setting_.Add(setting); // Например заполним данные, при добавление в контрол будут добавляться сразу данные, а в событие их можно сохранять в бд

   

 // обработчик изменения коллекции
    async void ListBoxSetting_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add: // если добавление
                if (e.NewItems?[0] is Setting newSetting)
                {
                   
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove: // если удаление
                if (e.OldItems?[0] is Setting oldSetting)
                {
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```